# segment tree node structure not clear

Tags: c++, data-structures, structure, segment-tree

I am trying to build a segment tree but the node structure is not clear can someone please explain the code i found

```
struct node{ 
int count;
node *left, *right;

node(int count, node *left, node *right):
    count(count), left(left), right(right) {}//what this part is doing please explain and how it affects the complexity of the segment tree as compared to other initialization method

node* insert(int l, int r, int w);};
```

Comment: The syntax is not right, last line. Ok, I mean syntax is poorly formatted. Still last line.

Comment: Why? It's inside poorly indented `struct`.

Comment: you could simulate a segment tree with just an array if you are just using it for learning purpose..

Comment: @coder `node(int count, node *left, node *right)` - this is a constructor, I suppose you know that. Then you just google "C++ colon after constructor".

Comment: as to what this part is doing,  look up construcor initialisation lists in c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you indicated is a constructor with an initialization list.  To make it more confusing it uses the same names for the parameters as it does for the member variables.  Perhaps less confusing, the exact same code could be written:

```
node(int cnt, node *lhs, node *rhs)
    : count(cnt), left(lhs), right(rhs)
{}
```

Or:

```
node(int cnt, node *lhs, node *rhs)
{
    count = cnt;
    left = lhs;
    right = rhs;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain the complexity part